# Redis timeout issue in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, timeout

We have implemented Redis using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis package in .net core web api application.In which we are facing timeout issue and below is the error for the same.

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout awaiting response
> (outbound=17KiB, inbound=0KiB, 7375ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms),
> command=EVAL, next: HMGET {redis cache key}, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 641,
> aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 131072, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe:
> 0, serverEndpoint: {redis server address}, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10
> available, clientName: {clientName}, IOCP:
> (Busy=298,Free=702,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=98,Free=32669,Min=4,Max=32767), v: 2.2.4.27433 (Please take a
> look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause
> timeouts:
> https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Below is out configuration in startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRedis, RedisCaching>();

builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
    {
        options.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetSection("{rediscacheendpoint}");

    });
```

and this DI is used in respective business layers like below

```
public class MyBusinessClass
{
    private readonly IRedis _redis;

    public MyBusinessClass(IRedis redis)
    {
        _redis = redis;
    }

    public Task<SomeClass> somemethod()
    {
       await _redis.GetValue<SomeClass>("somekey");
    }
}
```

Redis class

```
public async Task<T> GetValue<T>(string key)
        {
            T response = default;

            var cacheValue = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);

            if (cacheValue != null)
            {
                response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(cacheValue);
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Any help on this appreciated.